# How does mongoose's find() function hold on to its execution and wait for a later function in its chain to complete first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, es6-promise

I was going through some tutorial materials and I notice that in Mongoose, I could somehow defer the final execution of a promise in it but I wonder how that is done.

For example, I can call the `find` function and it returns the promise of the result likes so:

```
const blogs = await Blog.find({id : '123'});
```

The `find()` function in mongoose calls the `exec()` function in the Query object to complete the query and return the result, like [in the line of this file.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/aa5b97ba5ef79f5a1168c0e6bb30a4ac04a21947/lib/query.js#L1992)

Then, let's say that I have the following modifications to the prototype of the Mongoose Query object to see whether I should retrieve data from cache or from Mongo:

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function() {
   this.useCache = true;
   return this;
}

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function() {
   if (!this.useCache) {    // <-- Apparently, I don't understand how this.useCache can be true if this.cache() was called
      this.exec.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return 'some cached value';
    return this;
}

// Somehow, the find() section of the chaining is capable of waiting for cache() which is called later to complete to know that useCache is true! But how is that done?
const blogs = await Blog.find({id : '123'}).cache();  // <-- how did this mange to return 'some cached value'?
```

However, since `exec()` is already called and evaluated in `find()` which is executed before the `cache()` function in the chain, how could `this.useCache` still be eventually evaluated in the `exec()` function finally when it resolves?

Unless there are some ways to wait until everything else down the chain have finished executing, in this case `find()` waited for `cache()` to finish executing, I would have expected `this.useCache` to always be undefined, wouldn't it?

I thought it's pretty amazing and would actually like to know how to implement a similar kind of chaining that is capable of somehow deferring the final action until all the functions in the later part of the chain to complete before resolving a result.

**Note:**
The above examples are my simplified version of the actual code for readability sake. The links to their actual files can be seen [here](https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedNodeComplete/blob/master/AdvancedNodeStarter/routes/blogRoutes.js#L18) and [here](https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedNodeComplete/blob/master/AdvancedNodeStarter/services/cache.js#L17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `find()` function in mongoose calls the `exec()` function in the Query object to complete the query and return the result, like [in the line of this file.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/aa5b97ba5ef79f5a1168c0e6bb30a4ac04a21947/lib/query.js#L1992)

Actually no, it doesn't, at least not in your case. See [the comment from three lines above](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/aa5b97ba5ef79f5a1168c0e6bb30a4ac04a21947/lib/query.js#L1987):

```
// if we don't have a callback, then just return the query object
```

The `.exec()` method is only called by `find(…, callback)` if you pass a callback. When using promises, you don't.

Instead, the `exec` method [is called by the `then()` method of the query](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/aa5b97ba5ef79f5a1168c0e6bb30a4ac04a21947/lib/query.js#L4432-L4434) which makes the query *thenable*, and which gets used when you `await` the query object.

Comment: Ahh.. Thank you!